# Continuity of $f(x, y) = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{|x|} + y^2}$ at $(0, 0)$

Tags: calculus

I guess the function is not continuous at $(0, 0)$ but can not find a sequence which converges to $(0, 0)$ and for which $f$ returns a non-zero value. I also tried the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{|x|}+y^2\ge\sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you. That helped me.